# How to get the names of files present in <img> tags from a string and create an array of all those file names in PHP?

Tags: php, html, arrays, image, html-parsing

I've one sample string as follows :

```
$feed_status = Nice to see you all back again <img src=\"http://52.1.47.143/file/pic/emoticon/default/smile.png\" alt=\"Smile\" title=\"Smile\" title=\"v_middle\" /><img src=\"http://52.1.47.143/file/pic/emoticon/default/smile.png\" alt=\"Smile\" title=\"Smile\" title=\"v_middle\" /><img src=\"http://52.1.47.143/file/pic/emoticon/default/smile.png\" alt=\"Smile\" title=\"Smile\" title=\"v_middle\" />;
```

(Forgive me for syntactical errors like placing of single quotes and double quotes)

For your reference I've just added three `<img>` tags to the string but in real situation ths string could contain a single `<img>` tag or no `<img>` tag or more than one `<img>` tags.

I want to get names of files present in each of the `<img>` tag's src attribute and make array of those file names.

In this case the resultant array should be as follows :

```
$new_arr = {smile.png, smile.png, smile.png};
```

How should I do this in an optimum way using PHP?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1. Where are your quotes ? 2. Have you tried something?

Comment: @Rizier123:Please don't mark my question as duplicate. I really need a help from the community.

Comment: 1. I didn't marked it as dupe 2. IF you want that it gets reopened then explain why this is not a dupe! (And TL;DR is not an option to choose from)