# How to replace the <img> tag/s present in an string with another string that represents some code in PHP?

Tags: php, string, image, str-replace

I've one following string:

```
$feed_status = Nice <img src=\"http://52.1.47.143/file/pic/emoticon/default/smile.png\" alt=\"Smile\" title=\"Smile\" title=\"v_middle\" /> to see <img src=\"http://52.1.47.143/file/pic/emoticon/default/happy.png\" alt=\"Smile\" title=\"Smile\" title=\"v_middle\" /> you all back again <img src=\"http://52.1.47.143/file/pic/emoticon/default/tongue.png\" alt=\"Smile\" title=\"Smile\" title=\"v_middle\" />;
```

I've another array titled `$emoticon_codes` containing three elements which needs to be placed in above string in place of those `<img>` tags.

```
Array
(
    [0] => \ue056
    [1] => \ue057
    [2] => \ue105
)
```

The three `<img>` tags from the string should be replaced by the above three strings in same order.

How should I achieve this in an optimum way?

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

My final string should be like this after printing :

**Nice \ue056 to see \ue057 you all back again \ue105;**

I TRIED FOLLOWING THING :

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
      $doc->loadHTML($feed_status);
      $imageTags = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img');
      if(count($imageTags)) {
        $emoticon_codes = array();
        foreach($imageTags as $tag) {
          /*echo basename($tag->getAttribute('src'));
          echo "<br>";*/
          if (basename($tag->getAttribute('src')) == 'evilgrin.png') {
            array_push($emoticon_codes, '\ue404');
          }
          if (basename($tag->getAttribute('src')) == 'grin.png') {
            array_push($emoticon_codes, '\ue415');
          }
          if (basename($tag->getAttribute('src')) == 'happy.png') {
            array_push($emoticon_codes, '\ue057');
          }
          if (basename($tag->getAttribute('src')) == 'smile.png') {
            array_push($emoticon_codes, '\ue056');
          }
          if (basename($tag->getAttribute('src')) == 'surprised.png') {
            array_push($emoticon_codes, '\ue107');
          }
          if (basename($tag->getAttribute('src')) == 'tongue.png') {
            array_push($emoticon_codes, '\ue105');
          }
          if (basename($tag->getAttribute('src')) == 'unhappy.png') {
            array_push($emoticon_codes, '\ue403');
          }
          if (basename($tag->getAttribute('src')) == 'waii.png') {
            array_push($emoticon_codes, '\ue407');
          }
          if (basename($tag->getAttribute('src')) == 'wink.png') {
            array_push($emoticon_codes, '\ue405');
          }
        }
      }
```

Comment: Have you tried something ? Is this a follow up question from this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/29391333/3933332 ?

Comment: @Rizier123:Yes I tried on myself and successfully extract the <img> tags. Intentionally I've not put that code here since it's irrelevant to this question's context.

Comment: 1. Please add your attempt(s) to the question 2. Also add what the expected output would be 3. You're missing some quotes for the string

Comment: @Rizier123:Please check my question again I've added the expected result of string.

Comment: Now you've done point 2 but I also wrote a point 1 and 3

Comment: load the string into DOM, getElementsByName(img), then replace each img node in turn with a text node containing your array contents.

Comment: @MarcB:Please check the question again I've added the code I tried. Could you please add your code to it and post it as an answer? It would be really helpful for me as well as other community members.

Answer (score 1):

Not tested, but this would be the "proper" way to do it:

```
$arr = array(\ue056, \ue057, \ue058);
$html = 'your html string here';
$i = 0;

$dom = new DOM();
$dom->loadHTML($html);

$images = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');
foreach($images as $img) {
   $img->parentNode->replaceChild($img, $dom->createTextNode($arr[$i]));
   $i++;
   if ($i > count($arr)) {
      break;
   }
}
```